# Selecting grouped rows after first two rows SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

This is a bit of a tricky question/situation and my search fu failed me.

Lets say i have the following data

```
| UID | SharedID | Type | Date      |
|-----|----------|------|-----------|
| 1   | 1        | foo  | 2/4/2016  |
| 2   | 1        | foo  | 2/5/2016  |
| 3   | 1        | foo  | 2/8/2016  |
| 4   | 1        | foo  | 2/11/2016 |
| 5   | 2        | bar  | 1/11/2016 |
| 6   | 2        | bar  | 2/11/2016 |
| 7   | 3        | baz  | 2/1/2016  |
| 8   | 3        | baz  | 2/3/2016  |
| 9   | 3        | baz  | 2/11/2016 |
```

And I would like to ommit a variable number of leading rows (most recent date in this case) and lets say that number is 2 in this example.  The resulting table would be something like this:

```
| UID | SharedID | Type | Date      |
|-----|----------|------|-----------|
| 1   | 1        | foo  | 2/4/2016  |
| 2   | 1        | foo  | 2/5/2016  |
| 7   | 3        | baz  | 2/1/2016  |
```

Is this possible in SQL? Essentially I want to filter on an unknown number of rows which uses the date column as the order by.  The goal is to get the oldest types and get a list of UID's in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. Use a [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to assign a value to each row, partitioning by the `SharedID` column so that the count restarts every time that ID changes, and select those rows with a value greater than your limit.

```
WITH cteNumberedRows AS (
    SELECT UID, SharedID, Type, Date,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SharedID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM YourTable
)
SELECT UID, SharedID, Type, Date
    FROM cteNumberedRows
    WHERE RowNum > 2;
```

Comment: Ah these are all things I didn't know were possible, thank you for the insight. This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you mean but something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable t1 JOIN MyTable T2 ON t2.id NOT IN (
 SELECT TOP 2 UID FROM myTable 
 WHERE SharedID = t1.sharedID
 ORDER BY [Date] DESC 
)
```